# Using other languages rather than English for java strings (Persian as an example)

Tags: java, string, persian

I want to use Persian language as my string to print, it's alright when writing the program but it changes when running it.
What can I do to set it right?

The sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("سلام");
    }
```

The result in windows command prompt is only question marks(????????)
and in notepad++ it is like L╪│┘ä╪º┘à

**Persian is a middle east language like Arabic.**

Comment: What is the default encoding of the editor you are using?

Comment: Depeding on the Encoding of your soruce file (which should be UTF-8) your code is fine. The windows command prompt won't display UTF-8 unless you configure it to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how

Comment: I'm using notepad++ , not sure how should I find out the default encoding of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need UTF-8 encoding to support Persian (which uses a slight variant of the Arabic script).  In Java, UTF-8 data can be represented as byte array.  So one way of achieving what you want is to create a `String` from a byte array corresponding to the UTF-8 representation of `سلام`:

```
try {
    String str = new String("سلام".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(str);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
}
```

If you've never seen a `String` being created from a byte array before, then have a look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)).

**Caviat:** This answer will only work if your *editor* is also using UTF-8 encoding.  This is required so that when the Persian salam string is converted to a byte array, the encoding is correct.

Comment: I got this error when using encoding: unreported exception UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. when I used throws Exception it was printed wrong again.

Comment: Wrap the creation of the `String` in a `try-catch` block.

Comment: With try/catch code I get :can not find symbol  UnsupportedEncodingException error.